# When to use @using in my razor syntax view in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

And yes, I searched it on google I could not find the exact answer.

So, When to use `@using SomeModel` in my razor syntax view. I am new to ASP.net MVC 5 and I know that each view can be strongly bound to a model or a viewModel and we use `@model ModelName`. What will be the situation when I will have to use `@using` in my razor view. Any example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's a `ViewModel`? I think that's an imported C# class used by the view for doing stuffs with it. Right? What can I do with it?

Answer (score 8):

Every time you need to import a *namespace* inside your view. This is the same as when you import a namespace in a standard C# code file.

So, if you need to use a type which is declared in a different namespace than the View one, you'll need to add a `using` statement before using that type.

```
@using OtherNamespace

@{
    var example = new ExampleClass(); // full name is OtherNamespace.ExampleClass
}
```

Be aware that there is another method for importing namespaces inside Views in MVC 5, which uses the `Web.config` file located in "Views" folder (note that this is not the *global* `Web.config` file). You may add further namespaces by adding the following parts:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="OtherNamespace" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This way you will not need to add a `@using` statement inside the `.cshtml` file.

**[Edit]**

Regarding the `@model` statement inside a view, there are essentially two options:

```
@using MyNamespace.MyNestedNamespace
@model MyModel
```

Or, if you think you will not need any other types from that namespace:

```
@model MyNamespace.MyNestedNamespace.MyModel
```

There is no real difference, is up to you what you think is better for that view.

Comment: Thank you. But my confusion is when I already have a model at the top of the view with all the properties that view will need then why will I ever use @using. Can you give small scenario.

Comment: @Unbreakable Added a simple scenario. Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the answers above, you would typically use @using on creating form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, 
                                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
//TODO: Logic here
}
```

This provides convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects. For more reference you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: Thank you for showing this different meaning of @using. I have a question: The usage seems to be different from normal C#, because there you have to declare a variable like `using(var myVar = new ...) { ... }` - so the intention is to use a disposable object inside a `{ ... }` block. Is the @using there just to properly dispose the form object? and why do you need the `{ ... }` then if you're not referencing the form inside?

Comment: Yes that is to properly dispose it, and upon creating the BeginForm, it will create the appropriate form tags for you. You can inspect your element and you will see the form tags are inside.

Answer (score 1):

Many situations where you would need @using, for e.g. see below:

**You have a function the view**

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 public string StripHtml(string inputHTML)
 {
    if (inputHTML == null) {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    string noHTML = Regex.Replace(inputHTML, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
    string noHTMLNormalised = Regex.Replace(noHTML, @"\s{2,}", " ");
    return noHTMLNormalised;
}
```

Here my func need Regex from System.Text.RegularExpressions;

**Pass some new model class to another view**

```
@using Model.Customer
@model Model.User

var cust = new Customer();
cust.Name = Model.Name;
Html.RenderPartial("_CustomerDetails", cust);
```

Hope, it made some sense.